# Making js code async only on Desktop version

Tags: javascript, if-statement, asynchronous, blogger

I have an external JS file for a blogger blog, is it possible to make the async attribute work only if it's loaded on Desktop version , and only load the normal script without async if it's mobile version ?

```
<script async="async" src='example.js' type='text/javascript'>

</script>
```

Update :

I tried to use if cond .. and it seems to work, but could I call it just once and not have the script source link written twice ?

here is the code

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest == &quot;true&quot;'>
   <script src='example.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<b:else/>
   <script async="async" src='example.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</b:if>
```

Comment: This should be handled on server side instead.

Comment: Thank you  .. but unfortunately I can't control the server side :)

Comment: Can i just ask what possible scenario you would need async for desktop and blocking for mobile?  Sounds like something that would be properly handled at a design level

Comment: @MasonStedman .. I don't much about coding, i mostly follow tutorials , this may sound stupid but my issue is i wanted to async a JQuery script stored in an external file so it improves page speed and user experience in general, but when i use async on both desktop and mobile version , the async makes the nav menu of mobile stops working since it depends on the JQuery script and async it make it fail to work... and since i don't need this mobile nav menu to work on desktop version, i async,ed it to improve speed on desktop, and also keep the original script to work normally on mobile version

Answer (score 0):

As comment said, this *should* be handled server-side, but if you had no option other than to implement it client-side, it's possible:

```
<head>
  <script>
    const isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini|Mobile|mobile|CriOS/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    const script = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
    if (!isMobile) script.async = 'async';
    script.src = '/example.js';
  </script>
</head>
```

That said, it's generally a good idea to use `async` or `defer` regardless, so as to avoid blocking document parsing while the script is executing.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question .. I updated the question with the result so far :)

Comment: `but the script didn't load` I tested it, works on my end. (check your console for errors and your network tab / src attribute to ensure it's requesting the right file)

Comment: i checked again , and changed my source link , it loaded , idk why, but it works as async on both desktop and mobile version .. i was trying to make it async on desktop version only and without async on mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `b:attr` tag like the following

```
<script src='example.js' type='text/javascript'>
    <b:attr name='async' value='async' cond='!data:blog.isMobileRequest'/>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you , but it still result to async on both desktop and mobile version .. the 2nd code in my post solved the issue and it works now as i want it , the only thing left i was wondering abut is, could i just write down the script source once instead of repeating it , as the case with adsense code that we can write down the script src once and then call it multiple times across the page